# How to create combination of strings in R

Tags: r, string, vector, combinations

I have the following strings:

```
center <- "XXXXXXX"
sides <- c("aa", "bb", "cc") # Could be longer than 3 members
# string length of members could be varied.
```

What I want to do is to make list of string that append member of `sides` to the both end of `center` in *all possible combinations*,  yielding in:

```
aaXXXXXXXaa
aaXXXXXXXbb
aaXXXXXXXcc

bbXXXXXXXbb
bbXXXXXXXaa
bbXXXXXXXcc

ccXXXXXXXcc
ccXXXXXXXaa
ccXXXXXXXbb
```

How can I achieve that with R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `expand.grid` and `apply` with `paste`:

```
> apply(expand.grid(sides, sides), 1, paste, collapse = center)
[1] "aaXXXXXXXaa" "bbXXXXXXXaa" "ccXXXXXXXaa" "aaXXXXXXXbb" "bbXXXXXXXbb" "ccXXXXXXXbb" "aaXXXXXXXcc" "bbXXXXXXXcc" "ccXXXXXXXcc"
>
```

Or:

```
>  apply(expand.grid(sides, center, sides), 1, paste, collapse='')
[1] "aaXXXXXXXaa" "bbXXXXXXXaa" "ccXXXXXXXaa" "aaXXXXXXXbb" "bbXXXXXXXbb" "ccXXXXXXXbb" "aaXXXXXXXcc" "bbXXXXXXXcc" "ccXXXXXXXcc"
>
```

Or as @Wimpel mentioned, you could use `data.table::CJ` to get the combinations:

```
> apply(data.table::CJ(sides, sides), 1, paste0, collapse = center)
[1] "aaXXXXXXXaa" "aaXXXXXXXbb" "aaXXXXXXXcc" "bbXXXXXXXaa" "bbXXXXXXXbb" "bbXXXXXXXcc" "ccXXXXXXXaa" "ccXXXXXXXbb" "ccXXXXXXXcc"
>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
> do.call(paste0, expand.grid(sides, center, sides))
[1] "aaXXXXXXXaa" "bbXXXXXXXaa" "ccXXXXXXXaa" "aaXXXXXXXbb" "bbXXXXXXXbb"
[6] "ccXXXXXXXbb" "aaXXXXXXXcc" "bbXXXXXXXcc" "ccXXXXXXXcc"
```